# Modeling Difference-in-Difference with Multiple Treatments

Tags: stata, treatment-effect, difference-in-difference

I ran a field experiment across 100 cities. The cities belong to two types: Type_A(50 cities) and Type_B(the other 50 cities). From January 1 to February 30(The Pre-Treatment Period), I only collected data on my variable of interest y. From March 1 to April 30 (The Post-Treatment Period), I simultaneously applied two treatments on two different sets of cities: I randomly chose 10 Type_A cities and 10 Type_B cities for Treatment_1, and another 10 Type_A cities and another 10 Type_B cities for Treatment_2. 
I plan to use DiD (Difference-in-Difference) for modeling. How does the specification look like? I am confused because there are several things going on together: different types of cities, multiple treatments, before and after periods, etc.

In addition, if I want to implement the specification in Stata, how to do that? More importantly, how to compute the marginal effect of the treatments in Stata?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: What's the measure of your time component? Weeks? Were your treatments implemented at the same time?

Comment: The measure of time is day, and yes, the treatments were implemented at the same time (started on March 1). Thanks.